# Forking config git repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

I recently acquired a nice cozy VPS and started by cloning my bitbucket desktop configs repo with deployment keys. Over a week or so I made a lot of VPS specific changes. Now I want to preserve all those changes. I cannot just commit into my Desktop repo, so I guess I need to fork my repo, right? (I have very limited git experience, i.e. nothing past git clone & git commit) How do I do that precisely? I'm afraid to try anything myself cause obviously it's the LAST thing I'd want to bork on a server. Thank you for your time! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps

1. Create/fork a repo on bitbucket. Copy its git url.
2. Then, on your server,

   ```
   git remote add fork git://yournewrepo.git
   ```
3. Push stuff

   ```
   git add .
   git commit -m "server changes"
   git push fork master
   ```

Consult the [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) in case of any questions.

Comment: `git branch -u fork/master` will also let you use `git push` to push changes without specifying `fork` and `master` each time.